# Open e-mail message in outlook window from web

Tags: c#, html, outlook, exchange-server, outlook-object-model

I have a web page driven by data taken from an Exchange server using the Exchange Managed Web Services API. I'd like to add links to the email messages so the user can pre-read them before filing them but obviously don't want to re-render the message in a web page.

Instead I'd like to launch it in an outlook window, I know that all users have outlook installed on their computers. Does anyone know how to do this?

I thought that it might be possible to use an *outlook:xyz* address but it looks like something like this: [How to open Outlook "New mail message" window from VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537860/how-to-open-outlook-new-mail-message-window-from-vb-net) might be more likely.

Any ideas?

Thanks Stu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Outlook Web Access is pretty much the only way to do this. Unfortunately that's not possible with my organisation so if anyone has any ideas, let me know.